# Is S/MIME in iOS 7 buggy?

Tags: ios, mail.app, encryption, certificate

I recently imported my S/MIME certificate into iOS 7. I am able to read signed/encrypted message sent from my mac to the iPhone.

BUT

I am UNABLE to send signed / encrypted mails from the iPhone.

This is strange:

- First I open the Mail app and start composing a mail. Immediately I see that the messages will be send encrypted (according hint in the app). But how can the app know, that it will send encrypted mail BEFORE I entered a recipient?
- Also, as soon as I tap into one of the fields (CC, BCC, etc) the hint "encrypted" disappears
- I am not able to encrypt / sign mails

Pretty complicated to describe. Any similar experiences? Buggy?

Answer (score 2):

You need to have, installed on your iPhone, the public key of the person you intend to send an encrypted message to.

Mail.app on OS X imports the certificates of people who send you mail, automatically. On iOS, you have to do it manually, unless your iPhone is part of a corporate deployment.

It's easy! Simply find an email the recipient has sent to you, tap the checkmark icon next to their name, tap "view certificate", and tap "install".

[image: "Signed" indicator]

Answer (score 1):

The mail can only be encrypted as long as the recipient als uses S/MIME encryption and the mail client knows the recipient's public key. As long as you do not meet that requirements, your mail will be signed, will include a public key, but will not be encrypted.